# WordPress - Cropping thumbnails without losing quality

Tags: php, css, wordpress, thumbnails

I have a website on which there is a "shop" page. Each product has a thumbnail assigned to it.

I set a custom thumbnail size with this code:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
   add_image_size( 'products', 150, 84, true );
}
```

Cropping works fine, but when the image is too tall WordPress crops it to the "height" parameter and the final result is a thumbnail too narrow to look good.

Is there a way to make WordPress select a part of an image (150x84 px fragment) and use it as a thumbnail instead of resizing the image? It is important for thumbnails to stay at 150x84 px EXACTLY while not being too narrow or too short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer.

Even if WordPress does crop images while using the function I used here, it may do it improperly until thumbnails are regenerated. Short answer is: WordPress cropped my images, but it was flawed due to thumbnails not being regenerated.

To regenerate them please use this plugin:

[Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Answer (score 0):

You can select which part you want to crop.

You have to do it like this:

```
add_image_size('respuesta',320,200,array('center','center'));
```

If you want to crop the center of the image.

You can [check the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) to understand better this method.